# How to make aws workspace reboot when client disconnected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

So I have a script that controls what happens on the workspace when it's being used.

I'd like to add aws workspace api calls to check if the workspace has a client connected, and if it does not, it reboots the workspace.

I looked through the documentation and saw that I can place an api call to reboot, but I need to make sure the client is not being accessed. the reason for this is in case of a power or internet outage at the client, the workspace reboots, which also stops the script being ran.

Comment: I see that `describe_workspaces_connection_status()` has a `ConnectionState` field that is `'CONNECTED'|'DISCONNECTED'|'UNKNOWN'`, but I don't know what those states mean. Perhaps you could experiment to see whether they indicate that a user is connected to the Workspace?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein can you point me to documentation of how to access the API to execute the method please? I read describe_workspaces_connection_status() doc page I see what you mean, I'll test it out once I figure out how to access the API

Comment: You could [use the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workspaces/describe-workspaces-connection-status.html) or there are AWS SDKs for many programming languages (eg [here it is for Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workspaces/client/describe_workspaces_connection_status.html)).